# what are the standard rules for yes or no tarot?

Tags: tarot

Starting learning tarot for a while and tried a few tarot reading sites already.
It is quite fun to see one site [yesnotarot.org](https://yesnotarot.org/) to give yes or no tarot reading based on 2 tarot cards.
I was wondering if 2-card reading is more accurate than one-card reading, or is there any standard rule for yes or no tarot?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because tarot as a prediction tool is not a game.

Answer (score 0):

> if 2-card reading is more accurate than one-card reading

They are both equally accurate at 0%.